# Scheduling Django method with Celery

Tags: python, django, celery

I have this method:

```
def getExchangeRates(): 
    """ Here we have the function that will retrieve the latest rates from fixer.io """
    rates = {}
    response = urlopen('http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=c2f5070ad78b0748111281f6475c0bdd')
    data = response.read()
    rdata = json.loads(data.decode(), parse_float=float) 
    rates_from_rdata = rdata.get('rates', {})
    for rate_symbol in ['USD', 'GBP', 'HKD', 'AUD', 'JPY', 'SEK', 'NOK']:
        try:
            rates[rate_symbol] = rates_from_rdata[rate_symbol]
        except KeyError:
            logging.warning('rate for {} not found in rdata'.format(rate_symbol)) 
            pass
    return rates

@require_http_methods(['GET', 'POST'])
def index(request):
    rates = getExchangeRates()
    fixerio_rates = [Fixerio_rates(currency=currency, rate=rate)
                 for currency, rate in rates.items()]
    Fixerio_rates.objects.bulk_create(fixerio_rates)
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

I want to schedule this, let's say, for every day at 9am, except for weekends.

I haven't found some comprehensive tutorial on how to schedule this based on such a specific datetime, also, I don't know if I could schedule this method, or create another method in my `tasks` file that inherits this one, and runs at any specific date.

I do have the `celery.py` file in my project root, and the `tasks.py` file in my app folder.

Or, maybe celery isn't the way to go for this situation?

Any ideas?

Comment: First: you don't need celery for this, your OS already has a scheduler. Second; the ciode creating/updating the models should live in a management command (if you decide on using your OS scheduler) or in a celery task (if you really want to use celery for this), not in a view. And finally: a GET request __must__ be idempotent (must note change the server's state).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some django packages that let you manage "cron-like" jobs using django admin interface. I used in the past both django-chronograph and django-chroniker (https://github.com/chrisspen/django-chroniker). There is also django-cron (https://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html), but I never used it.

All of them have similar approach: you create one single entry on your crontab runninng something like `python manage.py runcrons` every minute, and on your `settings.py` you add the package to show it on admin.

Take a look on the documentation of either Chroniker or Django-cron for more info on how to set it up.

Comment: Thanks, django_cron seems the way to go

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use [Celery Beat](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) to schedule tasks that you need.

Answer (score 1):

Tasks can be scheduled with [Celery Beat](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html).

Celery Beat must be launched as another process. This `beat` process will kick scheduled tasks to the [celery `worker` process](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html) that will launch the tasks like any other celery asynchronous task. To orquestrate these two process usually is a good idea use something like [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) in production and [honcho](https://mitchel.me/2016/consolidating-your-dev-processes-with-honcho/) in development.

The scheduled tasks can be defined in the code, or stored in a database and handled through django-admin with the extension [django-celery-beat](https://pypi.org/project/django_celery_beat/)

To add it by code the easiest way is create another method in the `tasks.py` file. For your requirement for every day at 9am, except for weekends "it could look like this"

```
@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):

    # Executes every Monday morning at 9 a.m.
    sender.add_periodic_task(
        crontab(hour=9, minute=0, day_of_week=1),
        test.s('Happy Mondays!'),
    )
    sender.add_periodic_task(
        crontab(hour=9, minute=0, day_of_week=2),
        test.s('Happy Tuesday!'),
    )
    sender.add_periodic_task(
        crontab(hour=9, minute=0, day_of_week=3),
        test.s('Happy Wednesday!'),
    )
    sender.add_periodic_task(
        crontab(hour=9, minute=0, day_of_week=4),
        test.s('Happy Thursday!'),
    )
    sender.add_periodic_task(
        crontab(hour=9, minute=0, day_of_week=1),
        test.s('Happy Friday!'),
    )

@app.task
def test(arg):
    print(arg)
```